# jersey-spring5 conflicting with another spring libraries?

Tags: spring, java-8, jersey, tomcat9

i am trying to use Jersey with Spring 5 and faced with such error:

when i am trying to use jersey-spring5 or jersey-spring4 my project won't build. The main problem is that i even can't get logs and see what couses such error. This is all what i'm get with log4j2 enabled.

[Here is link to project repo.](https://github.com/Apollo917/java_test) It is simple project for reproducing error.

```
07-Jan-2021 11:23:33.540 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
11:23:34.212 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
11:23:34.250 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext
11:23:34.341 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions - Registering component classes: [class com.config.RootContextConfig]
11:23:34.373 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions - No component classes found for specified class/package [classpath:applicationContext.xml]
11:23:34.404 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
11:23:34.677 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
11:23:34.680 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
11:23:34.681 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
11:23:34.684 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
11:23:34.696 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.ui.context.support.UiApplicationContextUtils initThemeSource - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@d91f53]
11:23:34.697 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'rootContextConfig'
11:23:34.703 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory getSingleton - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'logFilter'
07-Jan-2021 11:23:34.749 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
11:23:34.735 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate lookup - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
11:23:34.737 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate lookup - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] not found - trying original name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].
11:23:34.737 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate lookup - Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain]
11:23:34.737 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource getProperty - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
11:23:34.749 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 527 ms
07-Jan-2021 11:23:34.750 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/TEST_war_exploded] startup failed due to previous errors
11:23:34.757 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext doClose - Closing Root WebApplicationContext, started on Thu Jan 07 11:23:34 EET 2021
[2021-01-07 11:23:34,769] Artifact TEST:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: You don' t see any error messages in that log? I see a couple.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha yes, me too, but when i comment jersey-spring5 dependency - it's works well.